# 405 (Method Not Allowed) Ionic 3 RestAPI

Tags: angular, api, symfony, ionic3, symfony-3.4

Anyone can help me please!

#### AuthProvider

```
registerUri: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/add';
    signUp() {
        let user = {
          firstname: 'admin2',
          lastname: 'admin2',
          username: 'admin2',
          email: 'admin2@admin2.com',
          password: '0000',
          createdAt: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
        };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let headers = new Headers();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          this.http.post(this.registerUri, JSON.stringify(user), { headers: headers })
            .subscribe(res => {
              resolve(res.json());
            }, (err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
        });
      }
```

#### RegisterPage

```
 register() {
    this.showLoader();
    this.authProvider.signUp().then((res) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
    }).catch((err) => { this.presentToast('Error, Try Again!') });
}
```

#### Controller

```
 /**
     * @Route("/users/add" , name="register")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request,UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {

        $data=$request->getContent();

        $user=$this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($data,User::class,'json');

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user,$request->request->get('password')));
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $response=array(

            'code'=>12,
            'message'=>'User created!',
            'errors'=>null,
            'result'=>null
        );
        return new JsonResponse($response,Response::HTTP_CREATED);

    }
```

#### Error

> OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/add 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/add: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.
>
> [Response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfbfq.png)

Comment: sounds like your client is doing post which your server doesn't allow. So your issue is with server side code/configuration.

Comment: It's a CORS issue, you need to enable CORS on your server

Comment: Post method works well in `Postman`. How to enable it in wamp server?, but i already installed `CORS` Extension in `Google Chrome`

Comment: I solved it, i forgot to install [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) in my `Symfony` project, Thanks anyway :)